# Convert code from Matlab to Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to convert some code from Matlab to Mathematica.
At some point I have

fspecial('gaussian', 11, 1.5)

I am confused about what will be equivalent to write in Mathematica.

In Matlab I get:

```
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001    0.0002    0.0003    0.0002    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
0.0000    0.0001    0.0003    0.0008    0.0016    0.0020    0.0016    0.0008    0.0003    0.0001    0.0000
0.0000    0.0003    0.0013    0.0039    0.0077    0.0096    0.0077    0.0039    0.0013    0.0003    0.0000
0.0001    0.0008    0.0039    0.0120    0.0233    0.0291    0.0233    0.0120    0.0039    0.0008    0.0001
0.0002    0.0016    0.0077    0.0233    0.0454    0.0567    0.0454    0.0233    0.0077    0.0016    0.0002
0.0003    0.0020    0.0096    0.0291    0.0567    0.0708    0.0567    0.0291    0.0096    0.0020    0.0003
0.0002    0.0016    0.0077    0.0233    0.0454    0.0567    0.0454    0.0233    0.0077    0.0016    0.0002
0.0001    0.0008    0.0039    0.0120    0.0233    0.0291    0.0233    0.0120    0.0039    0.0008    0.0001
0.0000    0.0003    0.0013    0.0039    0.0077    0.0096    0.0077    0.0039    0.0013    0.0003    0.0000
0.0000    0.0001    0.0003    0.0008    0.0016    0.0020    0.0016    0.0008    0.0003    0.0001    0.0000
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001    0.0002    0.0003    0.0002    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

I need to get the same in Mathematica too.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html), this command creates a **correlation kernel** for a gaussian filter. In mathematica, you can simply use [ImageCorrelate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCorrelate.html), and pass this kernel as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
GaussianMatrix[{5, 1.5}, Method -> "Gaussian"]
```

- 5 is the radius ((11 - 1) / 2)
- 1.5 is the standard deviation
- Setting the `Method` to `"Gaussian"` makes Mathematica use Matlab's equations